# Bing map AJAX vs Bing map control

Tags: dictionary, bing

Im just trying to ascertain the pros and cons of using

Bing maps 
http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/ajax/
and using Javascript to interact with the API by embedding the map into a web page,

or actually creating an account and using the control
http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/web.aspx

Do both ways give you all options or are there limitations to either option.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a newer version of the Bing Maps SDK that is out which is version 7. Much better than 6.3 which you linked to. 6.3 doesn't require a credential if I remember correctly but using 7 does. Really though, passing credentials isn't a big deal and doesn't mean much in most cases.

I would suggest using the SDK at http://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7#CreateMap1

I have had great success with it and they give you a lot of control through JavaScript.

I don't believe there is a "windows control" anymore. There is a mobile control you can use in Windows Phone 7 applications although I've found that the web version of the Bing map works really well.